# How to "pop one out" on a Rubik's Cube?

Tags: rubiks-cube

I am trying to follow this tutorial for solving a Rubik's Cube: https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/how-to-solve-the-rubiks-cube-beginners-method/. Step two says, among other things:

> If the white corner piece is where it belongs but turned wrong then
>   first you have to pop it out.

What is meant by popping the corner piece out? Hopefully it does not mean pulling the corner piece almost out of its socket so that you can twist it individually? I did not think that kind of "moves" were legal.

Answer (score 9):

Popping a piece out means to move a piece from where it needs to be back to the region of the puzzle where it can be more easily manipulated. This typically happens when the piece is in the right *position*, but wrong *orientation.* (It's where it needs to be, but it isn't solved.) Once it's popped out, it 'looks' just like a piece that was never in the correct spot to begin with, and can be re-inserted the correct way - this time with the correct orientation - like you would any other piece.

In the case of the corners on the first layer of the 3x3, it means to take a corner from the position where it needs to go, and move it to the layer opposite the one you're solving, where you can freely move it around again.

It also applies to edges on the second layer, when they're flipped the wrong way - you pop the piece out of the second layer onto the working region of the puzzle, so that you can put it back in the correct way.

Comment: For second layer wrong orientation, I use the F2L alg.